# Chrome and Safari follow caret when leaving visible area of contenteditable DIV within DIV with overflow:hidden

Tags: google-chrome, safari, scroll, contenteditable, caret

I'm having these troubles since almost 2 full days now and see this as my last chance to get a neat solution of my 2-page-editor before giving up.

Please use **Firefox** first and have a look at:
http://twopageeditor.bastianschulz.com/

STEPS:

1. set the caret into the last row "Exiles, similes, and reviles;"
2. press the "down arrow" key

RESULT: the caret is in the first row on page 2

Short explaination about the implementation:
- The editor contains two separate contenteditable DIV elements. 
- In case of leaving a page by moving with the cursor within an contenteditable DIV element, we just swap the places and positions of the DIV elements but the caret stays in the same DIV element. The page 2 which is on the left side, is still the same DIV element that was on the right side when we were still on page 1.
- When changes to the text are done, the unselected DIV element is blurred out because it might be out-of-date. When the selected DIV element is deselected again, its content is fully copied into the other DIV element so that all changes that have been done are kept and therefore synchronized with the other DIV element.

Now use **Chrome** or **Safari** (IE not at all, that will be my next issue...)
STEPS:

1. set the caret into the last row "Exiles, similes, and reviles;"
2. press the "down arrow" key

RESULT: the caret is in the first row 1 on page 2

BUT: this row is not visible. Press down arrow key again and it appears in the second row of page 2. When you press the arrow up key now, the content moves again, the caret is in row 1 and page 2 is displayed as it should (and like Firefox does it correctly).

REASON: right after you pressed the down arrow key on the first page you will see for a part of a second that content in this DIV is automatically scrolled by the browser so that the position of the caret is still visible. This causes a displacement of the DIV element by 20px of its CSS top attribute. When setting thereafter the new absolute value of top:-520px e.g. (the height of the page / viewport is 520px) this weird shifting of 20px is still there.

I haven't figured out a way how to stop this automatic scrolling of the content when its not visible anymore. Or at least to be able to kind of reset the contenteditable DIV back to its normal state.

Anyone ideas?

Cheers!